# Replace XML nodeValue via Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

OK, I have an XML/XSLT pairing **(inserted into my HTML via Javascript from 2 external files)** that creates a button on the page with the nodeValue taken from a tag called 'JobID' (a generated GUID).

```
<button id="5f8294ca-fe5a-4da9-847b-da99df999000" onclick="markFinished(this.id)" type="button">Finished</button>
```

Thus returning the id of the button to a function...

```
function markFinished(clicked_id)
{
    cid = clicked_id;
    document.write(cid)
}
```

The XML look like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CurrentJobs>
  <Job>
    <JobID>25657287-cc52-415b-8781-be37d5098656</JobID>
    <Status>a-current</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>5f8294ca-fe5a-4da9-847b-da99df999000</JobID>
    <Status>a-current</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>05a84779-5801-4645-a7f9-74529ea5298b</JobID>
    <Status>a-current</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>07df3deb-4935-4504-8822-a73ccea038ae</JobID>
    <Status>b-complete</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>078c496d-ac60-48e7-b9fe-a0e1f78ff2c5</JobID>
    <Status>c-upcoming</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>07ec868e-d294-4bb3-807d-00df66f5bab2</JobID>
    <Status>c-upcoming</Status>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobID>8bdeee5f-2bf6-4e44-8af8-69f600048dfe</JobID>
    <Status>a-current</Status>
  </Job>
</CurrentJobs>
```

I need a way for my function to match the clicked_id to the JobID and replace the nextSibling (Status) with 'b-finished'. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Currently just using Javascript to import both the XML and XSLT files. Would this be easier to do via jQuery?

Comment: everything is easier with jQuery.

Comment: Could you help answer my problem then?

Answer (score 2):

You'd do that by parsing the XML and traversing it nodes.

As the value you're looking for is the text, you have to iterate and check each element until a match is found, then get the next element and replace the text content of that

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");

function markFinished(clicked_id) {
    var cid = clicked_id;

    var nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('JobID'),
        match = null;

    for (var i=nodes.length; i--;) {
        if ( nodes[i].textContent.trim() === clicked_id ) {
            match = nodes[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match) {
        match.nextSibling.textContent = 'b-finished'
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/js8b83z6/)

Comment: Does the Fiddle not work? Do you have an XML string, or is it already parsed etc ?

Comment: The XML and XSLT are called from an HTML file via onLoad() in the body tag, so theXML is already parsed. The XML displays a production schedule. When the production department clicks the 'finished' button, It calls the markFinished() function and that job in the XML is moved to the bottom of the displayed XML doc.

Comment: OK, the fiddle seems to work, but the live script doesn't. How do I refresh the document body after the script runs? Also, is the script only changing the result inside memory or is it actually changing my XML doc? I would prefer the latter and have it saved.

Comment: The above example parses a string, if you want to update something in the DOM, you'll have to use DOM methods to access it ?

Comment: That's what I need to do, but I don't know how to do it. working with XML via Javascript is relatively new to me.